# Cannot implicitly convert type string to string[] in c# soap call

Tags: c#, wsdl

I am very much perplexed by the error, "Cannot implicitly convert type string to string[]" in a soap call I am attempting to create.  I am using VS2015 in C#. Looking at the code:

```
ServiceReference1.ServiceClient client = new ServiceReference1.ServiceClient();
ServiceReference1.Request req = new ServiceReference1.Request();
req.requestID = "validRequestIDString"; // I get the error here
```

If I am using Bear SoapUI I have no issues sending the same requestID and getting a valid response.

I am guessing that the error is telling me that the response is an array and not a single string but I know that is incorrect.

Any direction would be helpful. Thank you

Comment: Hover over `requestID` of `req.requestID` in Visual Studio - what does it show? (I don't see how the response can be relevant given that you haven't referred to it anywhere in the code you've shown.) Where exactly is the error?

Comment: _I am guessing that the error is telling me that the response is an array and not a single string but I know that is incorrect._ Compiler never makes mistake. atleast at this point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like:

```
request.requestID = new String[] { "validRequestIDString" };
```